# Text on buttons larger on real devices than on emulators?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a simple Pitch Pipe app to learn basic Android. I'm pretty much done - it has all of the features that I would want in a pitch pipe. However, on the two real-world devices I have tried it on, the text does not fit within the buttons as it does on the emulator. Instead of this:

[image: pitch pipe app image]

The text on the center button looks like this on a real device:

F # /

G b 4

Sorry I can't provide any screenshots of the phones I tried it on, they belong to friends. But it basically looks like the text is in justify mode as well as being too large, so it takes up 2 lines instead of one. How can I prevent this from happening? How can I account for different devices handling text differently? Should I use a font other than sans-serif-light? Thanks for any insight you can offer.

Comment: How are you generating this? Are you using the ArcLayout library? I had a similar issue with the size of things, and it was caused by the fact that the size values I was passing were just plain pixels.

Comment: I'm just using the standard XML. I am setting the background programmatically (to change the stroke color when pressed) but all of the sizes never change and they're all in dp.

Comment: This question is asked properly and is very clear. Why are there downvotes?

Comment: I've got a screenshot (Galaxy S7, Marshmallow 6.0.1). [s7 screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/F8NzZ3G.png). Notice how the sharps and flats are black and large. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

That's depends on measurement unit used when you set the text size.

For example, if you use 'sp', the text size will be relative to the device font size.

Comment: I used dp which is supposed to be resolution-independent, so why is it still happening?

Comment: Are you sure `dp` used on setting both 1. TextView width  2. TextView textSize ?

Comment: Well it's a button with text inside, so I am using dp for textSize, layout_width, and layout_height.

Comment: What about padding and margin ? same thing ? I suggest to set both to 0dp if you don't have any padding/margin.

Comment: Hmm, haven't considered that, thanks. I'll see if that fixes things.

Comment: I've got a screenshot (Galaxy S7, Marshmallow 6.0.1). [s7 screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/F8NzZ3G.png). Notice how the sharps and flats are black and large. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You should create different dimensions for your `textSize` to support different screen resolutions. Or programmatically, set the size of the text when the `lineCount` becomes two or more. You can get the lineCount using `getLineCount()` if you're using a `textView` and set the textSize like `text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);`

Comment: Well I used dp instead of pixels. I thought that was supposed to prevent problems with different resolutions?

Comment: use sp for fonts. Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

Comment: Well I can't use sp because the button size is constant - can't adjust that for user preference. So I need to keep the text constant as well.

Comment: Try to use `Button.setTextSize()`

Comment: I've got a screenshot (Galaxy S7, Marshmallow 6.0.1). [s7 screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/F8NzZ3G.png). Notice how the sharps and flats are black and large. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Some devices may use a system font that is slightly different from what your emulator has. The default font depends on version of Android (e.g. Lollipop uses [Roboto](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roboto)), but are often modified by manufacturers.

Note that in your case, there is another cause of confusion: if you measure the font size of the central button to match tightly F, then switching to A may cause split into two lines, because A is slightly wider than F. Therefore, dynamic adaptation of the font size may be necessary.

Comment: Ah, so what if I used a custom font? Or made sure that it had to use roboto?

Comment: you can use monospace font, but it won't look nice IMHO

Comment: Yeah I'm not a monospace fan either. I'm saying, what if I forced every phone to use a font I packaged with the app? Would that guarantee that all phones work the same? Also, as far as your F to A example, I've tested every button in the emulator, the only problems arise in real devices.

Comment: You should be okey if you use a packaged font, and test it on emulator for different DPIs. It may happen that with the same font the same glyph **A** looks a bit wider when rendered in **xxhdpi** *vs* **mdpi**, but at least there will be no device dependence.

Comment: Thanks. So could you answer this question about the way they "group" DPIs? So it seems to me that the app doesn't pass an exact DPI to the app builder - just whether it is xxhdpi/mdpi. Is this what leads to the small discrepancies in font rendering?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: When rendering text, we use dp or sp instead of pixels. When rendering for screens of different density, is the renderer given a generic group (xxhdpi, mdpi, etc) or the exact density? If the former is true, it could possibly be the reason the text is overflowing into two lines.

Comment: If font size and button dimensions are all set in same device-independent units, same logic would apply across all screens and all devices. If you mix px and dp, the result could easily go weird.

Comment: I've got a screenshot (Galaxy S7, Marshmallow 6.0.1). [s7 screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/F8NzZ3G.png). Notice how the sharps and flats are black and large. Any idea why?

Comment: From what I see, this is not the same font. You wanted to embed Roboto. Did you try?

Comment: Roboto doesn't include symbols, so I guess it falls back to Noto. Now to figure out why Noto doesn't have music symbols correct..

Comment: I've got it. Samsung replaces the standard font with their Emojis. I've got to figure out how to prevent it from doing that.